# How can I make an executable file with java netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee

How can I make an executable file with Java using NetBeans IDE that file work on computer or mobile. I create jar file but I don't know why it did not work.

Comment: Executable files that work on desktop aren't the same as files that work "on mobile" (which mobile?). Do a google search of "netbeans export runnable jar" for more information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272107/how-can-i-convert-a-jar-file-to-an-exe-file

Comment: An executable JAR file on a mobile? And you tag Java EE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [making executable file from a java project using NetBeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088607/making-executable-file-from-a-java-project-using-netbeans)

Comment: thanks very much for this information, I creating a dictionary but I don't know how to make a java file being executable file

Answer (score 1):

You can run jar file in case its manifest contains proper reference to class with `main()` function using command `java -jar jarfile.jar`. If you need Windows executable, you can use [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). For Android AFAIK you need to build `apk` file.

Comment: thanks I doing it this in cmd java -jar nameoffilejava.java but not happen any thing I create a dictionary but not display any thing

Comment: To execute java class, you need to do the following:

1. `public static void main(String[] args)` in your class;
2. Compile your class using command `javac Classname.java`;
3. Execute your class using command `java Classname`;

Comment: thanks I doing all this things that you are say but how can I make the file if I double clicked the file being worked as application. –