# Unable to create .exe from java file

Tags: java, exe, executable-jar

I have created `java` project that contains `6 Class file` and `1 java file`

And I run this project in `net beans IDE` now my problem is when I clean and build this project **am unable to create exe file**

How can I make this project as exe (an executable file)?

all `7 files` in one single as executable

and found this and tried from here [making executable file from a java project using NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088607/making-executable-file-from-a-java-project-using-netbeans)   Can some one help me to solve my problem

Comment: Haven't used netbeans in years but I would be surprised if it had any native executable compiling functionality. An executable .jar file is not the same as a Windows binary. You can try software like [exe4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/exe4j/files) if you really need that.

Comment: You may generate a jar archive and make a .bat file for the execution.

Comment: if you are looking for steps to create a executable jar in eclipse , enable the option 

Project Properties -> Build -> Packaging -> Build JAR after compiling

Comment: @vembutech i need to make the file as `.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The JAR file format provides many benefits.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html)
You can make your Java application runnable via a double-click by packaging it into an executable jar. 
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5258323/2830834) will help you.

Comment: i need to make all file as `.exe` file

Comment: Then you have to use 3rd party s/w like [Jsmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) for that.

Refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/147233/2830834)